# `packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)` doesn't return all apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I'm using

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> mApps = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
```

to retrieve a list of all installed apps. However, the list doesn't contain all installed apps, some (like Twitter, for example) are missing.

To test this, I'm using

```
int length = mApps.size();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
    PackageInfo info = mApps.get(i);
    Log.i(TAG, "Package: " + info.packageName);
}
```

`com.twitter.android` and others aren't among the logged strings, even though they are installed on the phone.

P.S.: I've also tried

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

which shows Twitter, but doesn't (obviously) return processes that can't be launched via the launcher, such as "Download Manager" or "System UI". I need a method that returns both system apps and third-party apps reliably.

Comment: Why do you think `0` is an acceptable argument for `getInstalledPackages`? Are you sure it's supposed to return system applications and not just user installed apps?

Comment: Using `getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)` has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by an error on my side (erroneously breaking out of the `for`-loop after a certain condition was met) and thus doesn't have anything to do with the PackageManager itself or the way that I was calling it.